# Getting data from Firebase and use data to allowed user of Android Apps

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'am new in Firebase Android in Kotlin.. I have made a registration form in my Android apps and send it to Firebase realtime database..After sending my data to Firebase I got like this.. I Just add access and fill it to "Allowed", so the user after register not directly can login to my apps...

[image]

here it is my login screen code..What I want is when ever the user click "login" button..The code will take the data which is "Access" if allowed than the user can login..if not there is a notification for contact the administrator..Please help me...I have tried so many time...thanks in advance

code:`package com.example.myapplication

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot
import com.firebase.client.Firebase
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register_form.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        login.setOnClickListener {

            val email = log_email.text.toString()
            val password = log_password.text.toString()
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Email is" + email)
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Password:$password")

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent) }
                    else { Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed, please check your account and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                }
        }

        register.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, register_form::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What's the question and what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: set email id as your key. Based on user we can pass email id and get the access value

Comment: the question is " when ever the user click "login" button..The code will take the data which is "Access" if allowed than the user can login..if not there is a notification for contact the administrator.."

Comment: I  use FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)..so after the data  have been sent..the new user can directly logged in....

Comment: Is the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) is successful ?

Comment: Hi Rajesh,...yes it succesfull.. But i  don't want User directly login to my apps.. The new user can login only if I add "Access" in my firebase database and set it to "Allowed"...

Answer (score -1):

set your Firebase rules rule of database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hei Praful..thanks for your respond..I used realtime database instead of Firestore...